# 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04 ./ Release' is not signed

Tags: apt, gnupg

```
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04 ./ Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 2F7F0DA5FD5B64B9
W: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04 ./ Release' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I am trying to get rid of the above error message seemingly related to release key and opensuse url.

What would be the proper solution?

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
wget -nv https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:selmf/xUbuntu_16.04/Release.key -O Release.key
sudo apt-key add - < Release.key
sudo apt-get update
```

[Source](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?package=libunarr&project=home:selmf)

Comment: Does not solve my problem: am getting `W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/manuelschneid3r/xUbuntu_16.04  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1488EB46E192A257
E: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/manuelschneid3r/xUbuntu_16.04  Release' is not signed.`

Comment: Out of all the solutions, this worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Because I use `lutris` for gaming I had to replace the username selmf or manuelschneider to `strycore` in those commands then it worked. Your error may be similar just swap the name out