# I can't update due to The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04 ./ Release' is not signed

Tags: apt, updates, repository

Whenever I try to update terminal tells me this

```
Ign:20 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04 ./ Release.gpg
Reading package lists... Done 
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04 ./ Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 2F7F0DA5FD5B64B9 home:strycore OBS Project <home:strycore@build.opensuse.org>
E: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04 ./ Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

The answer here ['http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04 ./ Release' is not signed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/954501/http-download-opensuse-org-repositories-home-strycore-xubuntu-16-04-relea) does not solve my problem.

Comment: What happened when you tried that answer? What was the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1397BC53640DB551](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133199/the-following-signatures-were-invalid-expkeysig-1397bc53640db551)

Answer (score 8):

The key is expired, you could try downloading it again.

```
wget -qO - https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04/Release.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: I get "gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found." I'm on Ububntu 18.04

Comment: this is not working as well

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve my problem by using cmd

```
curl https://build.opensuse.org/projects/home:manuelschneid3r/public_key | sudo apt-key add -
echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/manuelschneid3r/xUbuntu_20.04/ /' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:manuelschneid3r.list
sudo wget -nv https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:manuelschneid3r/xUbuntu_20.04/Release.key -O "/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home:manuelschneid3r.asc"
sudo apt update
sudo apt install albert
```