# Repository not signed issue

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager, repository

I use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with Lubuntu desktop. I had installed the minimal Ubuntu installation about 2 months ago and delayed the `apt.daily.service` to reduce boot time even more. A few days ago, when I tried to update the OS, it gave an error. I thought it might be temporary. But after a few days, it is still not working. I searched for the error but the solutions do not work.
When I try to do `sudo apt update`, it can get all the packages but I do not think they get installed. All my apps are up-to-date due to some preinstalled update manager. But not Ubuntu itself I guess.
The error:-

```
nachiket@Nachiket:~$ sudo apt update  
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]                                                          
Get:3 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease [10.4 kB]                                                           
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lubuntu-desktop/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                           
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Get:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]                                                        
Get:6 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease [2,590 B]                                                      
Get:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease [1,811 B]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Get:9 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main armhf Packages [35.6 kB]
Get:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [500 kB]                   
Get:11 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main amd64 Packages [34.8 kB]      
Get:12 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [1,081 kB]                                             
Get:13 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable/non-free amd64 Packages [1,151 B]                                          
Get:14 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main arm64 Packages [35.7 kB]                               
Get:15 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages [1,100 B]           
Get:16 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main Translation-en [238 kB]                                               
Get:17 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [282 kB]                                        
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [741 kB]                            
Get:19 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [60.5 kB]                                
Get:20 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [95.1 kB]             
Get:21 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [13.6 kB]                 
Get:22 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [318 kB]                     
Get:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main i386 Packages [254 kB]                     
Get:24 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted Translation-en [46.1 kB]                  
Get:25 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [831 kB]                                           
Get:26 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages [617 kB]                     
Get:27 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [24.5 kB]
Get:28 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe Translation-en [174 kB]                                           
Get:29 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [329 kB]                                    
Get:30 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [11.0 kB]                       
Get:31 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [362 kB]                   
Get:32 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [18.0 kB]                                    
Get:33 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse Translation-en [6,472 B]                  
Get:34 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,468 B]           
Get:35 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [16.5 kB]
Get:36 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main i386 Packages [2,568 B]                     
Get:37 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 Packages [2,568 B]            
Get:38 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main Translation-en [1,120 B]            
Get:39 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [400 B]              
Get:40 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe i386 Packages [4,716 B]               
Get:41 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 Packages [5,788 B]        
Get:42 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe Translation-en [2,060 B]
Get:43 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [1,780 B]
Get:44 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [7,956 B]
Get:45 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [288 B]          
Get:46 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages [628 kB]
Get:47 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe i386 Packages [502 kB]
Get:48 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe Translation-en [95.9 kB]                                           
Get:49 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [58.0 kB]                                    
Get:50 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [11.6 kB]                                     
Get:51 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]                                  
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                       
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/lubuntu-desktop/ppa/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/lubuntu-desktop/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.`
```

I can remove the ppa by `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:lubuntu-desktop/ppa` but can not remove it completely using ppa-purge. After removing, it still updates other softwares. But when I add it back, it gives the error.

Comment: Sorry for bad editing. I actually don`t know how to add terminal outputs in askubuntu. Please someone edit it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: No, I can remove the ppa by `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:lubuntu-desktop/ppa` but can not remove it completely using ppa-purge. After removing, it still updates other softwares. But when I add it back, it gives the error.

Comment: Your question asks about the apt update error. The question does not mention anything about unable-to-remove-software, nor provide input/output showing a failed package removal. Our clairvoyance is limited, so please help us to help you.

Comment: It is not related to any installation or removal of package of any software. It is about system update. The package that is causing this error is `lubuntu-desktop` (as mentioned above). Today, I tried to do system upgrade to 21.04 but I cannot do it because of this error. I have minimal Ubuntu installation with only Lubuntu DE. I neither have Unity nor Gnome. It is the only desktop and I want it to be up-to-date.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu\_16.04 ./ Release' is not signed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/954501/http-download-opensuse-org-repositories-home-strycore-xubuntu-16-04-relea)